# Specify dependency version >= for git repository in pyproject.toml

Tags: python, versioning, semantic-versioning, pyproject.toml

I have a python project with all dependencies and versions managed by `pyproject.toml` file.
One of these dependencies is a git reference:

```ini
[project]
name = 'my_package'
version = '1.0.0'
dependencies = [
    'my_dependency @ git+https://github.com/some_user/some_repo.git'
]
```

In order to improve version management after some time I started to use tags to specify exact "version". Like this:

```ini
dependencies = [
    'my_dependency @ git+https://github.com/some_user/some_repo.git@v.1.2.0'
]
```

But this is still not enough. Ideally I want something flexible, open for minor or patch version increase.
Like this:

```ini
dependencies = [
    'my_dependency >= 1.2 @ git+https://github.com/some_user/some_repo.git'
]
```

To be clear: I want `pip` to look for different versions in the entire repo history and take one's that match the condition. According to semver.

In this particular case with `>= 1.2` it should take `1.2.1`, `1.2.2`, `1.3`, `1.157.256` or any other commit with version in `pyproject.toml` (or at least git tag) greater or equal to `1.2`.

Is this possible?
Can `pip` manage versions so well for git repositories?

Comment: Unfortunately it's not possible. As specified here https://peps.python.org/pep-0508/ or here https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/requirement-specifiers/, you can't use of version requirements with url based dependencies. Your second approach about using tags is the one you need.

Comment: @Bloodbee
Please add this as answer. I'll accept it.

Comment: If use poetry to resolve your dependencies you can do that by specifying the `rev`: https://python-poetry.org/docs/dependency-specification/#git-dependencies

Comment: @grmmgrmm I don't need an exact match. I need `>=` according to semver rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not possible. As specified here https://peps.python.org/pep-0508/ or here https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/requirement-specifiers/, you can't use of version requirements with url based dependencies. Your second approach about using tags is the one you need.